# unity dependency injection - constructor with a multiple interfaces as parameters

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a set of interfaces and classes:

```
    public interface IA
    {
      ...
    }
    public class A: IA
    {
      ...
    }
```

The class I would like to inject dependency in:

```
    public class MyClass
    {
      private readonly IA _aRepo;
      private readonly IB _bRepo;
      private readonly IC _cRepo;

     public MyClass(IA aRepo, IB bRepo, IC cRepo)
     {
       _aRepo = aRepo;
       _bRepo = bRepo;
       _cRepo = cRepo;
     } 
    }
```

And dependency is:

```
public class Test
{
 private MyClass myClass;

 public Test()
 {
    //original call
    //myClass = new MyClass(new A(), new B(), new C());

    IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<IA, A>();
    container.RegisterType<IB, B>();
    container.RegisterType<IC, C>();
    //not sure what to do here...
    container.RegisterType<MyClass>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IA>(), new ResolvedParameter<IB>(), new ResolvedParameter<IC>()));

    myClass = container.Resolve<MyClass>();
}
```

}

I'm new to DI and would like to ask how could I resolve the injection for MyClass which accepts multiple interfaces as parameters?

Comment: Is the current code not working?

Comment: Please note that you don't need to register concrete types (classes) with unity. It can resolve them without registration. Also, you don't need to tell unity about the dependencies via `InjectionConstructor` (unless you have different implementation of the interfaces).

Comment: Hi Yacoub, thanks for your reply. You're right - I've removed the registration of MyClass. The problem lies in fact that one of my dependent classes has multiple constructors actually. Let's say class C. I'm getting "The type C has multiple constructors of length 2. Unable to disambiguate."

Comment: Why do you need two constructors for C? Can you show them?

Comment: The class C is a web service class in real terms and these constructors are auto-generated by web service. Could I somehow tell the unity which constructor to use? I have: public service(),  public service(string endpointConfigurationName) etc I need to call the default one

Comment: [Injectable classes should have a single constructor](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97). Since you cannot modify the class C, you can create a new class C1 that inherits from C and that has a single constructor that delegates to one of C's constructors that you want to use. And then register only C1 in the container.

Comment: Ok, I see, I'll try this one. Thank you very much Yacoub, I really appreciate your help.